# How do I add a policy to my Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I’m trying to set up a static website using Amazon AWS S3, and following [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-bucket.html). However, whenever I try to apply a policy to the root domain bucket so that people can see the website, I get an error.

The guide tells me to copy/paste the following into the Bucket Policy Editor, which I do, and I replace “example.com” with my bucket name as it tells me to do.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
  }
 ]
}
```

But every time I click “save,” I get a `Policy could not be parsed as a valid JSON string` error.

Comment: Take the policy you are generating and validate it with a tool such as the one at http://jsonlint.com.  If it is structurally invalid, that tool should give you some feedback about the error.  If your bucket already *has* a policy, you can't just paste an additional one into the box; you have to combine the new statement with the existing ones, or replace them if appropriate.

Comment: hmm… jsonlint.com says that it IS a valid JSON string. I haven’t added any policies, but maybe it’s conflicting with some setting i clicked. That’s a bummer. Thanks Michael!

Comment: Note how jsonlint cleans up the formatting?  Well... it should not matter, valid json should not depend on trivialities of whitespace... but you might try taking jsonlint's output and pasting it back into the S3 console.  No other setting should be able to cause a conflict here, fwiw.

Comment: I just copied and pasted this policy and added it as a bucket policy on one of my own buckets. As you talked about, I also replaced "example.com" with my bucket name. It worked perfectly and I got no error. I would guess you accidentally typed something extra.

Answer (score 0):

Silly Apple Mac TextEdit adds a different type of quotation mark "

Check any quotation marks and retype them in jsonlint.com

Should fix any errors as it did for me.